# Find if text contains phone numbers in Big Query

Tags: regex

enter code hereI am trying to find if a text column on Big Query has phone numbers in them.

I am currently using the following code:

Input table :

| text_field |
| --- |
| Hello please call us on +1 123 456 789 |
| Please allow 2 days for the purchase to reflect in your wallet |

Code:

```
select 
    text_field
from 
    table
where
and REGEXP_CONTAINS(text_field, r'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]') = True
```

Desired table :

| text_field |
| --- |
| Hello please call us on +1 123 456 789 |

However, I see many different formats of phone numbers written in many different ways. Example: +1 123 345 789, + 123-456-789 etc

 
Is there any general regular expression I could use to detect any phone number in the text field?

Answer (score 0):

if phone numbers are separated by commas, then you can use the following regular expression `'[^,]+'`
If the phone numbers are not structured, then the search is difficult. Or use `^\+?[178][-\(]?\d{3}\)?-?\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{2}$` only I don't know if the database supports such regular expressions